# Find and return multiple strings in a text file

Tags: bash, text-processing

I am looking for a way to extract strings from a file using bash, and append them to another file.  The file in question contains data with the following format:

```
Data="/dataset/0001" a bunch of random stuff I don't need Data="/dataset/0002" more random stuff Data="/dataset/0003"
```

et cetera.

I am looking to extract and return the strings between the double quotes (ie, `/dataset/0001`, `/dataset/0002`, `/dataset/0003`, etc.).

Any suggestions on how to go about doing this?

As a follow up question, it would be super neat to be able to prepend a constant string (for example, `/home/user`) before each returned value (ie, `/home/user/dataset/0001`, `/home/user/dataset/0002`, `/home/user/dataset/0003`, etc.).

Thanks for any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ grep -o 'Data="[^"]*"' file | sed 's,Data=",/home/user,; s/"$//'
/home/user/dataset/0001
/home/user/dataset/0002
/home/user/dataset/0003
```

This uses a combination of `grep -o` and `sed` to do the extraction and transformation of the data.

The `grep -o` pulls out each `Data="..."` bit onto separate lines, while the `sed` takes each of these lines and first replaces `Data="` with `/home/user` and then deletes the `"` at the end.

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda, that worked great.  I use grep from time to time, but it's all of those "extra" characters that I find the hardest to figure out.  

For instance, I can see what is happening with the wildcard (*) before the double-quote (include everything up to and including the final double-quote), but what is happening inside of the square brackets `[^"]` ?

Thanks again, I really appreciate this (and everyone else who contributed).

Answer (score 0):

With Perl:

```
$ perl -lnE 'say for map { "/home/user" . $_ } /Data="(.*?)"/g' file
/home/user/dataset/0001
/home/user/dataset/0002
/home/user/dataset/0003
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing it this way, because

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

but just for the sake of illustration, using repeated application of the bash `=~` operator:

```
#!/bin/bash

pfx="/home/user"

re='Data="([^"]*)"'

while read -r line; do 
  while [[ $line =~ $re ]]; do
    printf '%s%s\n' "$pfx" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    line="${line#*${BASH_REMATCH[0]}}"
  done
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the methods you may use to get the output:

```
perl -lsne '
  () = /Data="(.*?)"(?{print "$v$1"})/g;
' -- -v="/home/user" file 

grep -oP 'Data="\K[^"]+(?=")' file |\
xargs printf '/home/user%s\n'

sed -nEe '
  s|Data="([^"]+)"|\n/home/user\1\n|
  s/.*\n(.*\n)/\1/
  P;D
' file 

/home/user/dataset/0001
/home/user/dataset/0002
/home/user/dataset/0003
```